# Inserting a section of asynchronous code into a C++ function

Tags: c++, asynchronous

Okay, so I have a strong feeling that this is really easy to accomplish, and indeed something like this is pretty easy to do in other languages. Only that my C++ is not my strongest language, so I can't quite grasp how this should be done.

I have a function that does some startup things, and then part way through it needs to do some I/O and fetch data from another process. Naturally I could do this with callbacks, but I want to avoid doing this:

```
startupPt1() {
 /* stuff */
 ioCall(startupPt2());
}

startupPt2() {
 /* rest of stuff */
}
```

Really I want to avoid this because there isn't a logical separation between the actions that happen in parts 1 and 2 here, only that there is some I/O that we want to happen asynchronously in between them.

I currently have that I would use callbacks as above, but other than that I don't know what I should do.

Comment: Did you try anything already? Asking for _"Any ideas?"_ sounds too broad to be asked here. This may turn into an endless discussion which is what we don't want here. The site is rather about concise FAQ like question and answer pairs. You also may want to read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Comment: How about [std::async](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async)?

Comment: *"Naturally I could do this with callbacks"* You can use callback in C++. Look at `std::function`

Comment: I'm confused, do you want to use callbacks or no? You state that you want (need?) to use asynchronous IO, but your parts 1 and 2 are logically connected? What is it you actually need to know?

Comment: I think that maybe I've misspoken. What I need is for the process to suspend and surrender processor control while that I/O is happening, but to resume immediately when that I/O finishes. Callbacks are a solution here, but I would prefer if all of the actions lived in one function. There's not a clean way to separate them into `function1()` and `function2()`.

Comment: @Bronze Then just do the I/O in the middle of your 'part 1' and 'part 2'. It will be executed synchronously, i.e. part 1 -> I/O -> part 2. Execution wouldn't magically jump to part 2 as soon as I/O will start, unless you code it that way.

Comment: I'm still not sure what forces your I/O to be asynchronous. It seems that you want to have simple synchronous I/O?

Comment: That would require waiting in this process, which we don't want. There isn't a direct way to get the data I need, it's not like reading from disk. What we're doing is sending a message to another process, and we need that process to respond before we can continue. There's no way for us to immediately force the receiving process to respond. This other process also has other work to do, so it may not be able to respond immediately, either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, just to elaborate on my comments, you may want something like this:

```
#include<future>

//...

void startup() {
    // part 1
    auto result = std::async([](){
        // IO part
    });
    // part 2 not relying on the result of IO
    // part 2 that uses IO result as result.get()
}
```

This will allow OS to schedule your IO work for you. The only time you can guarantee it is finished is after you called `results.get()`.

Comment: This is exactly what I want. I wasn't understanding what you were getting at, but the code snippet makes it very clear. Thank you!